# What to do if you realize your question is misunderstood and downvoted too fast to edit?

Tags: discussion, questions, downvotes

I posted a question and after receiving a downvote and a comment with a link i realized my question was mistaken for one, which already exists, and that I needed to clarify it. In what felt like a matter of a few minutes I then got 4 downvotes and I think in that time i could not have made an edit to my question to clarify.

I did check for duplicates before posting my question and also had seen the question, which was suggested as a duplicate(it's fairly popular), among many others. I didn't think any of the questions I had looked through would be seen as a duplicate of mine. I lateron edited my question to clarify the differences to the suggested question, but it was too late and too many downvotes for someone to care about it still.

I guess I would wish for something like the possibility to "hide" my question while I'm making a substantial edit just to stop the flow of downvotes.

Or what else should I do? I left a comment (maybe too late?), but that didn't really help...

The inability to "halt" downvotes, which are because of a misunderstanding, make me feel quite uneasy (scared;) about posting new questions. I have also since deleted the question, because of the downvotes.

Comment: If you have no answer, you can delete the question, edit it, and undelete at your leisure.

Comment: Be aware and care to be quick in responding on this site. There are more people lurking on your question in real time, you even might imagine.

Comment: I've removed the [tag:feature-request] tag from this question because there is no clear **feature** presented in the question. If you really want to make a feature request please indicate exactly what form the feature would take. Otherwise, be ready to have your Meta question be downvoted. (Vague feature requests don't fare well on Meta.)

Comment: Word-smith your question to smithereens, *then* hit the Post Question button

Comment: Hm, i thought about deleting and undeleting, but i somehow assumed this was misuse of the feature and there was some "penalty" for it. But okay, I'll do that then from now on.

Comment: "I also already knew the (fairly popular) question and answer, which was suggested as a duplicate, so i was sure, that it was not like mine. I lateron edited my question, but it was too late and too many downvotes for someone to care about it still." If you were already aware of the question, you should have made explicit reference to it and explained why your question wasn't the same, before you posted it initially.

Comment: I don't think people should be downvoting a question because they think it is a duplicate. There are options to close a question as a duplicate if that is the case. If it was getting downvotes I'd personally assume that there were issues with the clarity of the question in some way. Maybe others use downvotes differently to me though...

Comment: I'm frustrated by this too.  I just posted a fairly lengthy question, after almost a day of searching Google, SO and the docs for an answer, and it was downvoted by some clod within ten seconds of posting.   Obviously they never read past the title and just decided to strike me with their furious lightning.   People like that are not an asset to SO.

Comment: @Louis Too late to fix, but I assume you meant to link to http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/feature-request - your link is missing the meta subdomain.

Comment: @Chris The downvote tooltip in SO reads "this question does not show any research effort;..." posting duplicates of famous questions is the evidence that no research has been done, and is worthy of downvotes. Like Antony said, it is OP's mistake not mentioning the difference between the possible dup and his question *before posting it*

Comment: @TiesonT. Yep. I used the automatic syntax `[tag:...]`, which always trips me up.

Comment: such a common situation :)

Answer (score 8):

In answer to your question here, you can delete the problematic question, improve it, then undelete it again. But make really sure it is worthy of being undeleted.

In response to your comment:

> i thought about deleting and undeleting, but i somehow assumed this
>   was misuse of the feature and there was some "penalty" for it. *But
>   okay, I'll do that then from now on*.

You shouldn't see this as a "system" or "function" to be used as part of your posting here. The point is to not get to that stage.

Before you submit your question (or answer) *for the first time*, proof read it.
If it's a complicated question, perhaps leave it alone for 5 mins, do something else, then come back and read it fresh so you know you are submitting a *good* question which won't be downvoted quickly.

> I also already knew the (fairly popular) question and answer

Another mistake really, then. Checking for dupes is a part of the checking and proof reading *before* you post the question for the first time.

Comment: I checked for duplicates before. Did you miss the rest of my sentence? "I also already knew the (fairly popular) question and answer, which was suggested as a duplicate, so i was sure, that it was not like mine." The suggested duplicate was unlike my question, it was not a duplicate. The text and content of my question was really quite different and it also wasn't closed for being a duplicate.

Comment: I was assuming that numerous members of community agreeing it was a dupe means it more than likely was, and so you did not put enough effort in to your original post to make sure it was not a dupe. I could be wrong, but without seeing the question and evaluating it, that was the assumption I made (sorry if it is unfair...)

Comment: My question was about text classification through machine learning, but i didn't even know these words before writing my question so i kind of wrote something along the lines of "have two sets of strings, where one fulfills condition and the other doesn't and want to know if new text does meet condition and by which rules". Unfortunately i wanted to use html texts as inputs and suggested that there be found some rules or patterns or regexes to classify, so that it was taken as a "parse html with regex" question and not as "classify input by learning from old input" question.

Comment: I also felt that there was some bias against me, because I'm a newbie and people were just skimming and not really trying to understand... oh well, i still got some good ideas from the comments, so that was already enough. ;)

Comment: Again, without seeing the question I cannot be sure, perhaps you are right and users skimmed through. However, my point was, you *knew* of a very similar question, so should have made sure yours was not going to be taken as a dupe of it. Again, perhaps users didn't read carefully enough. It happens

Comment: @blinci How do you expect everyone else to know that you know about the possible dupe if you don't explicitly explain why the dupe isn't applicable to your problem?  I have seen a fair number of people (especially new to SO) who insist that their question is a special snowflake and can't possibly be answered by another question already.

Comment: I had seen the other question, but from my perspective it was quite different from my question, so I didn't think someone would think it would be a duplicate. I checked for duplicates, found none, the only thing I could have done was to write "I looked through a lot of questions, but none of them were applicable to my problem."

Comment: @blinci: Explicitly adding "this differs from question X in way Y" is not always amiss. I've done that myself on occasion, when something is likely to be misread on a skim.

Comment: @blinci "I looked through a lot of questions" is as convincing as "searched a lot" or "spend 2 days". If there is no clear indication of what you've tried (in form of "tried this, did not work because ....) such phrases will only increased chance of getting down-votes/close vote.

Answer (score 5):

I see four possible solutions:

- Delete the misunderstood post and create a new one.

  Make sure the new post is clearer so that people will understand it well.
- Freeze the post while you fix it, to prevent more downvotes.

  As [@James explained](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/280711/1529630), you can delete your post, improve it, and then undelete it.
- Fix your current post, without freezing it

  This has the risk of getting too much downvotes. However, if the fixed post is good enough, the community will eventually upvote (or undownvote) it.

  There is a chance that you will even gain some reputation. When people see a downvoted post which doesn't deserve to be downvote, they tend to upvote it to counteract the downvotes. But in terms of reputation, one upvote counteracts five downvotes in case of answers, or 2.5 in case of questions.
- Do nothing and hope someone will understand what you meant.

  Probably this is not the best option in case you want someone to answer your question.

Comment: "Do nothing" on post with -4 votes is not really an option as pretty much no one will be looking at such post. Note that answering highly down-voted post is sometimes consider "feeding help vampires" and may even get undeserved downvotes to answer...

Comment: @AlexeiLevenkov Yes, but it's a possible way of dealing with the problem. A not very intelligent one, though.

Comment: I second @Oriol: there is no reason for blindly down-voting an _answer_ for a bad _question_. The question might be badly written and not understandable by many of us -- and so deserve down-votes. But that doesn't prevent _one_ to actually understand what was written and to provide a decent answer. In such case, a much more constructive approach would be to _edit the question_ on the light of the answer given.

Answer (score 4):

A good idea is to *quickly* **leave a comment** saying:

> Seen that, the problem I have is different. Working on an edit to explain further.

You'll still get a few bad apples who downvote even after you've said that, but doing so really goes against etiquette; there shouldn't be enough like that to be a problem.

Answer (score 1):

Prevention is better than cure.

If you search for duplicates before posting, and find some near duplucates but conclude that your question will be unique, don't just post your question as you originally formulated it. Refer to those near duplicates, explaining *why* your question is not a duplicate of those other questions.

Answer (score -1):

The fact that the question you asked received down-votes shouldn't stop you from asking questions. It is just a reminder of the fact that your question needs to be clarified. You can always delete it, edit it, and then undelete it. And I am sure that after people understand your question properly, they shall up-vote it.