# What should I do if I accidentally post a question before I'm done writing?

Tags: discussion, questions

I just posted [a question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/37284048). The substance of it isn't really important; what is is that I accidentally posted it when it was [absolutely terrible](https://stackoverflow.com/revisions/37284048/1). Thankfully, everything turned out fine, because I put a (now-deleted) comment on it informing people that I dun goofed, and they withheld their downvotes.

However, it raises the question of "what should I do when I post a question before I meant to?" That is, I'm halfway through writing it and accidentally post the incomplete, and probably bad, version. Should I do what I did, leave a comment, and hope people notice? Is there some other way to do it?

---

I've [seen it said](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/280699/what-to-do-if-you-realize-your-question-is-misunderstood-and-downvoted-too-fast#comment131896_280699) that you can delete, edit, and undelete, but when I tried, I was unable to edit the deleted question.

Comment: I would just cut my losses and delete it, even if it meant re-typing it.

Comment: It sounds like you encountered a [meta-tag:bug]. What exactly happened when you tried to edit it?

Comment: You can quickly select the whole post and copy it before deleting it. Spares you some effort. (Did that before)

Comment: I think the same also applies to answers when you fat finger the "Post" button. It happened to me a couple of times. I just deleted, edited and undeleted after that. If you couldn't do that, maybe you encountered a bug?

Comment: You can't edit your question if you self delete it. From the [FAQ on MSE:](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/5222/266735) _"Self-deleted posts can be viewed and undeleted by their original authors. However, self-deleted questions cannot be edited by their authors unless undeleted first."_

Comment: That said, you _can_ edit it when undeleted, copy and paste the markdown to your favorite text editor, delete the question, edit in the text editor, then undelete and quickly edit to paste in your new text from your text editor.

Comment: Oh so it's not the same an answers, thanks for the info @Kendra. Learned something.

Comment: If you're fast enough, you can get what you need, delete...get everything ready... undelete and paste. But if you find yourself doing this more than once, you probably should just write all your questions offline.

Comment: As an aside, consider typing your question on [meta] so you can see a preview, and upload images etc. Then when you're satisfied you can copy+paste it into [so]

Comment: The struggle is real - I have a Q&A pair that's in progress as we speak. As a precaution I think I'm going to open the web inspector and disable the submit button.

Comment: Get a browser extension that auto-saves any text in inputs, like Lazarus. https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/lazarus-form-recovery/loljledaigphbcpfhfmgopdkppkifgno?hl=en. saved me a lot of time

Comment: @TankorSmash Oh, that's cool! I'll be sure to install it once I get around to switching to Chrome :)

Comment: @QPaysTaxes: I use the Firefox version of Lazarus (and have for years) :P

Comment: Throw yourself on your sword.

Comment: @mtyson That should be an answer, not a comment :P

Comment: What should I do if I accidentally post a comment before

Comment: @mtyson - the type of sword may be important here. Gladius? Broadsword? Katana? Cutlass? Sabre? Machete? ???

Comment: I'm slightly scared that this discussion of me throwing myself on my sword has gotten any momentum. I have no honor already; why would I try to save some?

Answer (score 47, accepted):

I did something like this not long ago (for an answer, not a question, but that shouldn't matter much).

I quickly edited the answer, adding a bold line at the top, something like:

> ***Hang on a moment, I posted this before I was finished. I'll update it.***

Then I re-edited it, finishing what I had to say and deleting the warning.

The incomplete version was visible only for a few minutes. If I had deleted it, the deleted version would have remained visible to high-rep users. (On the other hand, it's harder to run across a deleted question by accident.)

(I don't remember which post this was, so I can't provide exact details or a link.)

Comment: Oh, that's a good idea! Better than mine because more people are likely to see a notice at the top of a question than a comment.

Comment: I [wrote a query to find the post](http://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/query/488352) (because I'm weird), but I came up empty. Someone else could play with it if they want.

Comment: @Mr.Bultitude: Anyone who wants to search through the 2635 answers I've posted is welcome to do so. 8-)}

Comment: I'm accepting this answer, because it seems to be the consensus after a very long while of waiting.

Answer (score 21):

Delete broken question and ask new one when you have finished off-line composing the post is likely the best option for high-traffic tags. For lower traffic tags delete, compose in your favorite editor and re-open with quick edit immediately after un-delete.

Note: questions can't be edited [if self-deleted](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5221/how-does-deleting-work-what-can-cause-a-post-to-be-deleted-and-what-does-that/5222#5222) (unlike answers). So copy raw content before deleting to continue editing off-line / in a new question. If you want live preview consider editing question in a deleted answer of yours so you can save your work (make sure to revert back after posting real question).

Comment: This raises the question why you can't edit a self-deleted question. Delete-edit-undelete seems the natural way of dealing with this situation.

Comment: @user000001 Oded explained his thought process [in the comments on his answer when it was implemented.](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/178760/couple-of-issues-with-roomba-turbocharging/179555#179555)

Comment: If the reasoning is that spammers are going to abuse edits on self-deletes to evade review queues, it seems like a reason to put undeletes into the review queue (or bump them onto the main page like we do for regular edits), not to disable edits on self-deletes.

Comment: @BrendanAbel You should bring that up on Meta.SE

Comment: @kendra [direct link](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/178760/couple-of-issues-with-roomba-turbocharging/179555#comment810259_179555)

Comment: I dislike this because (**a**; this may not actually be the case) if you're close to a question ban, this may push you over the edge, and if you're taking the time to make a good question (i.e. you've learned) that's probably a bad thing and (**b**) it feels weird to just have a deleted, unused, partial question sitting on the site. However, it most certainly would work.

Comment: @QPaysTaxes: Yeah I was just going to mention this. I think it's less of a problem for established users - or rather, the risk that you'll get question banned is lower. Still, a very valid concern, since we all know by now that it's probably best to avoid having to delete your question as much as possible.

Comment: @Kendra It seems to me that a low-traffic spam post isn't that big of a problem. What kind of spammer wants posts to be essentially invisible? I'd call that a win. If we assume that the `view:flag` ratio is constant for spam posts, then the spam posts have the same detrimental affect, regardless of their lifetime. Having said that, it seems like the obvious answer is to push edits on questions into a queue, rather than restricting users from legitimate workflows.

Comment: @BoltClock is it really an issue for question-ban to delete 0-votes post? (assuming user is not throttled/banned yet)?

Comment: @Rob IIRC a spam flag puts it into a special queue for mods, so if even one person flags, the post will probably be deleted.

Answer (score 2):

Whenever I do that, I just hit "edit" or if I post it way too early I'll copy what I have to clipboard and delete, make a new post and paste what I already did to it.

Comment: OP said, he can't edit the Question, I tried that too. Edit is not enabled for the question, so you can't copy the content.

Comment: Ctrl+shift+I on chrome will allow you to go into the HTML and you can copy from there. in other browsers just go to "inspect source" or something like it and you will be able to copy anything that is on the webpage.

Comment: @Arulkumar Edit is available, that person deleted the question first therefore there was no edit.