# What happens when you delete a question or an answer?

Tags: discussion

In Keith Thompson's answer to this post [What should I do if I accidentally post a question before I'm done writing?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/323217/what-should-i-do-if-i-accidentally-post-a-question-before-im-done-writing?cb=1) He states,

> The incomplete version was visible only for a few minutes. If I had
>   deleted it, the deleted version would have remained visible to
>   high-rep users.

I have also seen on the Meta [List of all badges with full descriptions](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/67397/list-of-all-badges-with-full-descriptions),

> A positive question record means you don't have too many closed,
>   downvoted or deleted questions, overall. The formula is (total
>   questions - negative questions - closed - deleted)/total questions >=
>   0.5. Questions that have been downvoted and closed and deleted count three times in this calculation!

So I was wondering if someone could explain the technical flow of what happens when you delete a question. Is it stored somewhere? Visible to moderators or high rep users?

Comment: See the section "What does deletion mean for a post?" in the [How does deleting work?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/5221/234299) FAQ on Meta.SE.

Comment: You're older, shorter of breath and one day closer to becoming a jQuery developer..

Answer (score 3):

> Is it stored somewhere? Visible to moderators or high rep users?

Yes, deleted posts are *soft deleted*. They still reside in the database and are  visible for ♦ moderators and other users with more than 10k reputation.

It might need that a direct link to that post is captured somewhere, is it in the browser history of the *moderator/high rep user*, or anyone else left a link, e.g. in a Meta Stack Overflow post.

Note it's not possible to actively search on the site for deleted posts as well.

Comment: I'm glad such a rule is in place, such that no post can be deleted such that someone with 10k+ reputation couldn't see it.  *(I mean, after all, their reputation is over 9000!)*

Comment: @HostileFork Well, +10k rep users are trusted to wear their _sun-glasses_ when spotting deleted questions to prevent them from getting blinded :) ...